# why block_ops_in block_ops_out is alway zero in mysql?

Tags: mysql, io, database-performance

I use sakila database of mysql to study `show profile statement`。
I found this explanation in mysql reference manual:

> BLOCK IO displays counts for block input and output operations

I think it means count of occurring block io in disk, but `block_ops_in` and `block_ops_out` always is 0 in practise:

```
select * from employees;    
show profiles
show profile all for query <query id> // why block_ops_in、block_ops_out is zero? It's impossible
```

Did I understand `BLOCK IO` wrong? or this sql didn't occur disk io ??

If I want to know how many io occurring in disk when a sql executing, what should I do?

Comment: Relevant MySQL doc link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/show-profile.html